# Appending to an Array of Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a complex structure. It's a `Dictionary` indexed by `String`, that contains an array of `[String: String]` dictionaries:

```
var t: [String: [[String: String]]] = [:]
```

My problem is: when I try to append values to the list, by doing the following:

`t["key1"].append([val1: ..., val2: ..., ...])`

I get this error: `Cannot invoke method 'append' with an argument list of type [String: String]`

Is there a way to fix this? I tried initialising the `t["key1"]` list, by doing `t["key1"] = []`. This didn't help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var t : [String: [ [ String: String] ] ] = [:]

t["key1"] = []
t["key1"]!.append(["a key":"a value"])
```

Comment: It works ! Strangely, @ridvankucuk's solution works aswell. Thumbs up to you two !

Answer (score 2):

Your t value is a dictionary and you are trying to append it. You can do it like this:

```
t["key1"] = []
t["key1"]?.append(["a":"b"])
t["key1"]?.append(["c":"d"])
```

Comment: And how can I actually append values to this ? The result I'm looking for is [["a":"b"], ["c":"d"]]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is it necessary to write t["key1"] = []?

Comment: Yes it is. You should init your array before append the data. As you see the key has Optional type. If you dont init your dictionary will be empty.